# update_attributes on nested forms does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have a nested form and trying to update it using update_attributes but it doesnt seem to work. I am using rails 2.3.8

Can you please help?

Aanu

adding some code

controller code:

```
update
@app.update_attributes(params[:application])
end
```

@_params:

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"AdSr8o51u7GfnOwLSpEOe5xAPINd7ImxDpuayPk12No=", "_method"=>"put", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"10006", "stype"=>"Save", 
"application"=>{
    "contact_attributes"=>{"city"=>"Denver", "address"=>"7000 Drive", "zip"=>"22222", "first_name"=>"Randy"}, "details_attributes"=>{
        "2"=>{ "coverage"=>"false", "same_fee"=>"true", "fee_rate"=>"2000", "id"=>"10018", "year_estabilished"=>"2005"}
    }}
}
```

Comment: In order to get help please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` defined in your model? Have a look here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: looks like [(based on this link)](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4766-nested_attributes-fails-to-updatedestroy-when-association-is-loaded-between-setting-attributes-and-saving-parent) there is an issue with update_attributes in 2.3.8. I would like to know if there's any work around for that.